# Installing library (written in C/Fortran) on MacOS - fatal error: 'sys/statfs.h' file not found

Tags: c, macos, compilation

I'm trying to compile a library that was written in Fortran/C for Linux under MacOS. The compilation aborts with the following message:

```
copen.c:150:10: fatal error: 'sys/statfs.h' file not found
#include <sys/statfs.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
1 error generated.
make: *** [copen.o] Error 1
```

The problematic part in the file copen.c is:

```
#include <sys/statfs.h>
```

This header-file is apparently not available under MacOS. I tried to replace the above line with

```
 #include <sys/param.h>
 #include <sys/mount.h>
```

, which seem to provide the same functions under MacOS. But then another error appears:

```
copen.c:160:10: fatal error: 'sys/fstyp.h' file not found
#include <sys/fstyp.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [copen.o] Error 1
```

which is caused by the following lines in the file copen.c:

```
#if defined (_AIX)
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#define  FSTYPSZ  16
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <sys/vfs.h>
#else
#include <sys/fstyp.h>
#include <sys/fsid.h>
#endif
```

Is it somehow possible to compile this library under MacOS by replacing certain lines where header files are included? Or is there another way of solving this issue?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in your question to give you an answer.  Try commenting out the missing headers, only then will the compiler errors tell you what names (functions, macros, and structures) are missing/different includes on MacOS that the program requires.

Comment: What library are you installing? Is it currently maintained? Does it have instructions for installing under MacOS, or a list of dependencies? We need a little more information here.